# How can I rescue a Jade plants half-killed by mold?

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, mold, jade

I have a Jade plant which had a trunk shaped like a Y. After getting back from a few weeks vacation, one "leg" of the Y was completely wilted and limp looking. Looking closer, I noticed that there was some mold growing at a crack in the "segments" of the trunk. I decided to completely cut off the part above the mold.

Now I see that there is still some mold growing where I cut. How can I save this plant and prevent the mold from getting to the other half?

[image: Broken trunk of Jade plant showing white-grey-blue mold growth]

Answer (score 1):

The jade plant is quite tough. It will sustain long spells of dryness and will reproduce via its stalks whenever it can. Because it's a succulent, it loves direct sunlight and heat, so I would put it inside on a windowsill and stop giving it water, during its recovery. The mold could be due to excess humidity, so that new scenario would help as well on that front.

Reading up [more info](https://www.thespruce.com/grow-jade-plants-indoors-1902981) on the plant is always useful.

Best of luck!